# Sharing session state using web.config not reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, reflection, web-config

I'm sharing session variables in two different asp.net web applications.

I'm using "StateServer" mode.

For sharing, i set **_appDomainAppId** of the **HttpRuntime** same for applications with using reflection. In **Application_Start** function, here is my code:

```
            string applicationName = "mysite"

            FieldInfo runtimeInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            HttpRuntime theRuntime = (HttpRuntime)runtimeInfo.GetValue(null);
            FieldInfo appNameInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, applicationName);
```

Here is my question : I don't want to use reflection for this. I want to handle this in web.config.

Is there any way to set **_appDomainAppId** in web.config ? I couldn't find anything under the httpRuntime section or anywhere else.

Thank you.